# Bootstrap popup missing when compulsory radio button not selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a group of style radio buttons as part of a form that is located below the submit button. Selecting one of these buttons is compulsory.

This is what my code looks like currently.

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
         <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Rate!</button>

    <div data-toggle="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-primary"> 
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="1" class="sr-only" required>1</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="2" class="sr-only" required>2</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="3" class="sr-only" required>3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

When I click submit without clicking one of the radio buttons, I get a popover message stating that I must select at least one the buttons (as one would expect). However, if these radio buttons are not visible on the same screen as the submit button, and the submit button is clicked without selecting one of the radio buttons, the screen scrolls down to the appropriate place but does not show any popover message. This can be reproduced in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahg1jfrv/).

My question is why does the browser not show a popover message by default if the buttons are not visible on the same screen, and how I could change my code to enable the behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not bootstrap showing the popover message, but the browser. It would be more intuitive to put the radio buttons *before* the submit button.

Comment: @Gerard, I have edited the post to update that. The radio buttons were placed after the submit button intentionally. My use case is different to a standard form.